# Ajax request returns multiple answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 radio inputs who are showing different information on the page on change. One of the radio inputs is called "Équipe Existante". By clicking on this one, I modify the display to block on an id "existingTeamWrapper" who is wrapping a p tag and a Select list. On the code, I tell to that Select list on change, to execute an ajax code. At this point, everything works fine. I receive the data as it supposed to be. But... Theres a thing... When I check my requests in my dev tools, I see that I receive multiple useless answers for the same request. What I noticed is I receive the same amount of ajax answers as the time I clicked on the radio input "Equipe Existante".

I tried to return false on the change function a the end of the execution, I also tried to execute something else to the Select list when I change tab, but it doesnt work, I still receive useless answers. The answers are added even if I click on the checked radio input...

Someone can help me out?

[image: Code]

[image: Ajax request]

Comment: So...I think you've done a good job of [Introduce the problem before you post any code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) however, could you work on some of the other _How to Ask_ points including "don't post images of code".  Without looking, though, my guess is that you are attaching a listener multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't bind the `change` handler inside the `click` handler. Every time you click on the `existingTeam` button, it adds another `change` handler. Then when you change `#existingTeamSelect`, it runs the `change` handler multiple times.

Move the call `$("#existingTeamSelect").change()` outside the click handler.